# We got to try tip, but we got poblano chili cheese grits

Tags: pronunciation, listening, culture

I heard [[28:30-28:40] part of this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/H0bA72fjHMQ?t=1710) as "*We got to try tip, but we got poblano chili cheese grits. Maybe(?) it's gonna be amazing.*"

Did I hear right?

If so, does he mean he should have ordered steak and tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like:

> "We got ta' tri-tip, but we got poblano chili cheese grits baby! It's gonna be amazing."

1. "try tip" is actually "tri-tip" and while there is no difference when spoken aloud, a [tri-tip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tri-tip) is "a triangular cut of beef from the bottom sirloin subprimal cut." The speaker is stating the specific cut of steak that was ordered.

   - Other examples would be [New York Strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strip_steak) or [Filet Mignon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filet_mignon). Which could be expressed as "We got ta' strip, but..." or "We got ta' filet, but..."
2. The word before "tri-tip" sounds to me like a "ta'" which is an informal spoken contraction of the word "the". The implication being that "the Tri-Tip" is the menu item being ordered or possibility *the* (only) tri-tip offering on the menu.
3. The word at the end of that phrase is "baby!". The exclamation "baby" is used to indicate excitement.

This sentence overall seems to express that while they got a tri-tip steak and poblano chili cheese grits, the "We got X, but we got Y baby!" construction indicates that the speaker is more excited about Y (the poblano chili cheese grits) than X (the steak).

Comment: Thank you very much. Did the speaker order both Tri-Tip and Poblano chili cheese grits, or only Poblano chili cheese grits?

Comment: The speaker ordered ("got") both items. The only difference I can see is the level of excitement about the different items. (As a guess) It may be that the steak is something more common (it's "just" a steak), but the poblano chili cheese grits are something unique or special (making it the more appealing item of the two items ordered).